# Что значит эта ошибка и как ее исправить (org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException)?

Tags: android, обработка-ошибок

Гугл показал, что на устройстве HM NOTE 1LTETD (dior) Android 4.4 произошел сбой (первый за месяц у всех пользователей всех устройств). Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем суть ошибки и как исправить. Место: android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{пакет/пакет.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class TextView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class TextView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.a.ac.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.a.s.setContentView(Unknown Source)
at пакет.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)// выделена строка гуглом
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
... 11 more

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/button_task.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020048
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2139)
at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2062)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3558)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623)
at android.support.v7.widget.bg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.widget.bg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.a.ac.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.h.ac.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
... 21 more

Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag ripple
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:935)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:879)
at android.content.res.Resources.createFromXml(Resources.java:2515)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2135)
... 31 more
```

Код используется в ресурсы/drawable/разметка кнопки в xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/color_button_start_s">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/color_button_start_t" />
    </shape>
</item>
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот ваша ошибка "invalid drawable tag ripple". Тэг  `<ripple>` нельзя использовать в версия ниже 5.0+

Comment: Благодарствую. Вы не подскажете, миллиардер Гугл не удосужился написать библиотеку поддержки, что-то наподобие android.support.v21, которая бы решала вопрос с <ripple>? Если нет, то чтобы Вы посоветовали сделать? (добавил пример кода в вопрос)

Comment: Вот тут, вроде бы есть решение https://github.com/ozodrukh/RippleDrawable

Comment: Благодарю. Не смог разобраться до конца. Решил использовать селекторы для версий до 5.0.